# Trouble triggering onKey event with Android

Tags: java, android, key, listener

I'm having difficulty getting my main View's onKey event to trigger.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I have correctly implemented the onClick event but cannot seem to figure out the onKey event.

Here's the relevant code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private RelativeLayout main;
    private ApplicationToolbar toolbar;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        this.main = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.main);
        this.toolbar = new ApplicationToolbar(this);

        //  toolbar is added to main later on in the code...

        this.main.setOnClickListener(mClickListener);
        this.main.setOnKeyListener(mKeyListener);
    }

    private OnClickListener mClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    // Works correctly.
        }
    };

    private OnKeyListener mKeyListener = new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            toolbar.setBackgroundColor(0xFF0000FF);    //  Does not work.
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

In fact, no matter what code I put within mKeyListener it does not execute, which leads me to believe that the event itself is never being triggered, even when I pressed a bunch of keys on my physical keyboard (Motorola Droid, Android 2.1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try overriding `onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)`

Check:

- [Back and other hard keys: three stories](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html)
- [is there a default back key(on device) listener in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592037/is-there-a-default-back-keyon-device-listener-in-android)

Comment: Thanks, overriding the onKeyDown event works, and it is a viable workaround for my situation.  Any idea why my method above does not function properly though?

Comment: @celestialorb: Perhaps you don't have any `RelativeLayout`'s child `onFocus` when you press a key. Try adding an `EditText` inside.