# Overriding Back Button Action in Activity

Tags: android, overriding, back-button

I have just overide my back button in my code like this

```
        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                return true;
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
          {

                 {
                       startActivity(new  Intent(context, MainDialog.class));
                       finish();

                return true;
            }
            return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
        }
```

Now I am facing a weird problem,
I have a edit text on the current Activity.
At the time of editing when I am trying to close the virtual keyboard by pressing the back
button .
My Application finishes...
But I just want to close the keyboard not the Avtivity..
Any suggestion to solve my issue..?

Thanks in advance,
Tanmay

---

```
I have tried both 

       @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
        {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {

               startActivity(new  Intent(context, MainDialog.class));
               finish();
               return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
```

and

```
        @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
        {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ) {

               startActivity(new  Intent(context, MainDialog.class));
               finish();
               return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
```

But no result.
Any suggestion!!

Comment: possible duplicat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592037/is-there-a-default-back-keyon-device-listener-in-android

Answer (score 4):

It seems you missed the if statement that catches the back key code. Try this:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            startActivity(new  Intent(context, MainDialog.class));
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One more solution probably, can we do like this...

I have an ImageButton by id buttonBack in xml
I am getting hold of that on btnBack and adding an OnClickListener

In public void onClick function I call an intent of the class which is having another layout probably the previous one class...hope this works for all... thanks.

```
ImageButton btnBack = (ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.buttonBack);
    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Your.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

        }
    });
```