# Respond to physical back button on Android

Tags: android, back

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is there a default back key(on device) listener in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592037/is-there-a-default-back-keyon-device-listener-in-android)

How can I respond to the physical back button in my Android application?
Like a listener of a sort.

I want to do things when that button is pressed!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand your question, simply override [`onBackPressed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) in your Activity for API 5+.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: While this technically overrides the back button, it doesn't change the default functionality.  You need to control when super.onBackPressed() is called or not called to stifle or allow default handling.

Comment: Sorry my ignorance @Error454 I'm new to Java and Android, if I want the back button to do my own action and not the default action I can simply omit `super.onBackPressed()`, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown( int keyCode, KeyEvent event )  {
    if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0 ) {
        // do something on back.
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown( keyCode, event );
}
```

You can find more information on the [Android Developer's Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html).

Comment: I actually prefer this solution, as it allows me to support Android 1.5