# How Stop Sound when back or home button is pressed

Tags: button, audio

My question is how to stop the media player when the user presses the back or the home button? I really need help..Can some one please give a code and tell me where to incorporate it in the activity.

This is my code:

MY JAVA CODE:

```
public class fbactivity extends Activity  {

    private MediaPlayer myMediaPlayer;
    private MediaPlayer my1MediaPlayer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 



  myMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(fbactivity.this, R.raw.milyonlarcataraftaryanyana);
  //Button related to play btn
  Button myButtonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.magnumsilah);
  myButtonOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          myMediaPlayer.start();
    }
  });

  //Button related to stop btn
  Button myButtonTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button03);
  myButtonTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          myMediaPlayer.pause();
      }
  });


 my1MediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(fbactivity.this, R.raw.sevmeksenideligibiyurekister);

  //Button related to play btn
  Button myButtonOne1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
  myButtonOne1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          my1MediaPlayer.start();
      }
  });

  //Button related to stop btn
  Button myButtonTwo2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
  myButtonTwo2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          my1MediaPlayer.pause();
      }
  });


  Button butongeridon=(Button) findViewById(R.id.geridon);
butongeridon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent i=new Intent(fbactivity.this,MainActivity.class); // the names of activity as per you program.
            startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
});

}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [is there a default back key(on device) listener in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592037/is-there-a-default-back-keyon-device-listener-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You inflate two buttons, one from `R.id.magnumsilah`, and another from  R.id.Button03. However, the ClickListener is bound to only one of them, and no listener is bound to the back button.

[It may well be worth it to be more thorough in you research before posting questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592037/is-there-a-default-back-keyon-device-listener-in-android). Just a thought.